# Get range of active object (image) in excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I know this is incredibly simple, I just can't seem to figure it out or find the answer elsewhere. Ill I want to do is get the range of a selected image. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Image and range are different objects in Excel. Can you be a little more specific about what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here sample how to get top-left and botton-right cells of picture on excel sheet. The picture has to be selected.

```
Sub test()
    If (VBA.TypeName(Selection) = "Picture") Then
        Dim pic As Excel.Picture
        Set pic = Selection

        Dim topLeft As Range
        Set topLeft = pic.TopLeftCell
        Debug.Print topLeft.Address

        Dim bottomRight As Range
        Set bottomRight = pic.BottomRightCell
        Debug.Print bottomRight.Address
    End If
End Sub
```